# How to Set Up SharePoint App development environment without configuring DNS

Tags: search, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, configuration, dns

I set up SharePoint Stand-alone farm in a machine within organisation where DNS configuration is not control by us.

So is there anyway we can skip this DNS or any workaround in SharePoint APP environment setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, instead of modifying DNS settings, you can update your local `hosts` file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

In this file you need to put your app host url and IP address. For example

> 127.0.0.1 app-f75ce1e9bc1ac8.myapp.com

Usually you put your localhost address and that's good for development. So the browser, when opening your app with address `http://app-f75ce1e9bc1ac8.myapp.com` will use your local SharePoint.
Don't forget to disable loop back check also.

Comment: Even then i am getting DNS unresolved error, is there anything additionally i have to do?

Comment: Can you please explain where do you getting this error?

Comment: Once i deploy the app in Developer site template and try to access then I am getting DNS unresolved error. while i pinged the url in cmd i'm getting my IP address

Comment: Also When the url in my browser is the same kmapps-1a8fdfe008cbdb.kmapps.com

Comment: What is the url of your site and what is the hosts entry you created?

Comment: url of my site is [link] (http://kmapps-1a8fdfe008cbdb.kmapps.com and the host entry is  ip address    kmapps-1a8fdfe008cbdb.kmapps.com

Comment: If you can ping `kmapps-1a8fdfe008cbdb.kmapps.com` from cmd, then this configuration should work. Make sure you configured all other parts correctly. Also make sure that computer where hosts modified and where SharePoint installed is the same computer.

Comment: I can ping and it returns the IP address. But still DNS unresolved message. Is that anything obvious i am missing?

Comment: DId you put 127.0.0.1 or real ip address?

Comment: also is it provider-hosted or sharepoint-hosted app?

Comment: It is simple SharePoint hosted app without much custom code in it.

Comment: Hmm... I'm really out of options... I did this multiple times without issues

Comment: i used real IP Address

Comment: Try to use local one, ie 127.0.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50518/discussion-between-john-zachariah-and-kai).

Comment: It worked as mentioned i have looked for the Organisation server proxy used in my browser and cleared the same. and it worked as expected